# Using SAS and Linux to send email with reference to macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to send an email using SAS from within Linux, In the body of the email I have a reference to a macro.

```
* store &a in macro for use in email; 
proc sql noprint;
    select tot_sendt into :a from tot;
run;


* sending email;
filename m email subject="Report A is ready (%SYSFUNC(today(),ddmmyy10.))"
to = ('myemail@email.com');

data _null_;
  file m;
  put 'Report A ready;
  put 'Totalt sent is:' &a; *a is a number stored in a macro;
run;
```

However, this code throws the following error: test_pgm.log.140825.1227:ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the COMPILATION phase.
test_pgm.log.140825.1227:ERROR 557-185: Variable set is not an object.

I have also tried

```
  put 'Totalt sent is &a'; a is a number stored in a macro
```

Which just writes &a in to email body.

Comment: FYI to other users - I'm going to use the question I marked this duplicate to as the 'reference question' for any identical issues.  Don't add a new answer to them, just mark as duplicate.  You can find it easily on a search for `[sas-macro] single quotes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro variables won't resolve inside of single quotes.

```
put "Totalt sent is &a" ;
```

should work.

Also note you are missing the closing single quote on your first PUT statement.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks! Spending an hour on a single/double quote issue - again...